# More than one language file and one enter point

Tags: java, internationalization

I have a Java program and I have more than one languages, I'm using i18n with this structure:

```
package languages;
import languages.it.ItLanguage;

enum ListLanguages {
    IT,
    EN,
    FR
}

public class Languages {

    ItLanguage language;
    

    public Languages(ListLanguages lan) {
        switch (lan) {
            case IT: {
                this.language = new ItLanguage();
                break;
            }
            case EN: {
                // this.language = new EnLanguage();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] getStrings(String item) {
        return this.language.getStringArray(item);
    }

    public String getString(String item) {
        return this.language.getString(item);
    }
}
```

I wish to call the constructor `Languages` passing the language to use and after to call this object to have the string, like in following way:

```
Languages lan = new Languages(it);
lan.getString("s1");
[...]
Languages lan = new Languages(fr);
lan.getString("s2");
```

But I cannot find a solution to avoid the switch inside the methods like `getString`:

```
switch(languageChosen) {
case("it"): return this.itLanguage.getString(item);
case("en"): return this.enLanguage.getString(item);
}
```

is there a solution to avoid this switch`?

The other class (for more information) is:

```
package it.bper.languages.it;


import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

public class ItLanguage extends ListResourceBundle {
    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] {
                {"name", "Pippo"},
                {
                        "ourfeatures", new String[]
                        {
                                "Б, Г, Д, ё, Ж, П, Ф, И, й, Л, Ц, Ш, Щ, Э, e Ю Я",
                                "Null",
                                "Empty"
                        }
                }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Java supports polymorphism, you would use an interface here: Provide `interface Language` defining the `getString` and `getStrings` methods, and implement them in LanguageIt and in similar classes.

In general, defining classes like `LanguageIt` makes most sense if they provide language-specific behavior. If they only return different data, you may also have only one `Language` class and in there place the data in a `Map`, using the enum as the key. The `getString()` style methods can then simply lookup the data by that enum key.

This is the `interface` variant:

```
enum ListLanguages {
    IT,
    EN,
    FR
}

public class Languages {

    private Language language;

    public Languages(ListLanguages lan) {
        switch (lan) {
            case IT: {
                this.language = new ItLanguage();
                break;
            }
            case EN: {
                // this.language = new EnLanguage();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public String getString(String item) {
        return this.language.getString(item);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Languages lan = new Languages(ListLanguages.IT);
        System.out.println(lan.getString("Peter"));
    }
}

interface Language {
    String getString(String item);
}

class ItLanguage implements Language {
    public String getString(String item) {
        return "Grazie "+item+"!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot do it because `'getString(String)' cannot override 'getString(String)' in 'java.util.ResourceBundle'; overridden method is final` in others terms I don't use `extends ListResourceBundle` on `ItLanguage` class

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution (thanks to PHolzwarth):

```
package testi18nv1;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Languages lan = new Languages(ListLanguages.IT);
        System.out.println(lan.getString("P"));
    }
}
```

Class Languages:

```
package testi18nv1;

public class Languages {

    private Language language;

    public Languages(ListLanguages lan) {
        switch (lan) {
            case IT: {
                this.language = new ItLanguage();
                break;
            }
            case EN: {
                // this.language = new EnLanguage();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public String getString(String item) {
        return this.language.getStringX(item);
    }

}
```

```
package testi18nv1;

import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

class ItLanguage extends ListResourceBundle implements Language {

    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"PETERS", "Peter parker"},
                {
                        "ourfeatures", new String[]
                        {
                                "Charlie",
                                "Localization Workflow Management",
                                "Localization Process Automation"
                        }
                }
        };
    }

    public String getStringX(String item) {
        return this.getString(item);
    }
}
```

```
package testi18nv1;

enum ListLanguages {
    IT,
    EN,
    FR
}
```

```
interface Language {
    String getStringX(String item);
}
```